# Instead of doing `months.map()`, cannot it be done by `modis.map()`?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

The following code creates monthly mosaics.

```
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
  .select('EVI');

var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);

var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function(m) {
        return modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))                    
                    .mean().multiply(0.0001)
                    .set('month', m);
}));
```

Any alternative to above code? Instead of doing `months.map()`, cannot it be done by `modis.map()` way?

Comment: It can't be done using modis.map(). A map function always returns as many items as it is given. If you want 12 items, 1 for every month, you can't give it more than 12 to map over.

Comment: Compositing by two weeks, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370617, is it correct?