# Compositing by two weeks

Tags: google-earth-engine

I tried compositing by two weeks.

```
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD43A4')
  .select('Nadir_Reflectance_Band2');

var twoweeks = ee.List.sequence(1,365,14);
print (twoweeks);

var byTwoWeeks = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      twoweeks.map(function(w) {
        return modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(w, w, 'DAY_OF_YEAR'))                    
                    .mean().multiply(0.0001)
                    .set('week', w);
}));


print (byTwoWeeks);
```

Output would be 27 items, one for every two-weeks.

Is this code correct?

How can I check that images are grouped correctly?

When I tried as follows.

```
var byTwoWeeks = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      twoweeks.map(function(doy) {
        return modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(doy, doy, 'DAY_OF_YEAR'));
}));


print (byTwoWeeks);


ImageCollection (Error)
ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type. Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>. Actual type: List<ImageCollection>. Actual value: [<ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite right. Right now you're always taking only the mean of a single day. So you need to add some amount to the `end` parameter of `calendarRange()`.

This should do what you want:

```
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD43A4')
  .select('Nadir_Reflectance_Band2');

var twoweeks = ee.List.sequence(1,365,14);
print (twoweeks);

var byTwoWeeks = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      twoweeks.map(function(w) {
        return modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(w, ee.Number(w).add(13), 'DAY_OF_YEAR'))                    
                    .mean().multiply(0.0001)
                    .set('week_start', w);
}));


print (byTwoWeeks);
```

Comment: okay, how about 2nd part of the question?

Comment: You can't easily check if it groups correctly when using `.map()`. If you take a single number you can check what is happening in that case. For example: `print(modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, ee.Number(1).add(13), 'DAY_OF_YEAR')))`